# Updating UI in batches with RX c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, system.reactive

I'm having an issue with updating WPF UI with the RX. Currently I have a class that has an event which is called within its functions. Event is subscribed from the UI thread and updates the UI like below :

SomeClass.cs

```
public partial class SomeClass
{
    public delegate Task ProgressUpdate(string value);

    public delegate Task BarUpdate(int value);

    public event ProgressUpdate OnProgressUpdateList;

    public event BarUpdate OnProgressUpdateBar;

    public async Task DoSomething() 
    {
      // execute code
       <some code>
      // update UI

      if (OnProgressUpdateList != null)
       {       
           OnProgressUpdateList(update);             
       }       
    }
 }
```

And in MainWindow.xaml

```
var someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.OnProgressUpdateList += Export_OnProgressUpdateList;
someClass.OnProgressUpdateBar += Export_OnProgressUpdateBar;


private async Task Export_OnProgressUpdateList(string text)
{
     await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
       {
           OutputLog.AppendText(text);
           OutputLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
           OutputLog.ScrollToEnd();
        });
 }
```

This code works except the program processes huge number of files and I'm assuming this is why the UI becomes frozen very quickly (I see the updates being done in the first half a second). I searched for a way around this and I came into a solution to use RX for batching the UI calls. I've searched through several SO posts but I couldn't find an answer on how to correctly implements this (or convert C# events to RX observables) when I call those events from the class and subscribe to this event from outside that class. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: The UI becomes frozen because you are constantly repainting the view.  Try using a timer and only repaint once a second or slower.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying in the original question - help me understand how to batch UI calls via RX. There are several threads that are constantly firing UI update events hence the freeze. I know what to do, just don't know how to.

Comment: Remove OnProgressUpdateList and instead put the code inside a timer.

Comment: Think in terms of a FIFO queue.  Add your changes to the queue. Discretely from  that you need a process reads off that queue and applies the changes then stops for a while. Then repeats. You could use await task.delay(500)  in a loop rather than a timer specifically. You could consider a blockingcollection. You will want a way to stop that ui update loop with a bool.
I don't think you should be using RX if you're having trouble with this. I suggest you stick to inotifypropertchange notification in mvvm toolkit.

Comment: @Trollfurion - FYI - methods starting with `On` are for raising events, not the events themselves. It's non-standard naming the way you have it.

Comment: @Trollfurion - Also, please be careful with events based on delegates that return something. Only the last subscribed event's return value comes back to the call that raises the event. Any earlier subscriptions are "fire-and-forget".

Comment: @Trollfurion - And finally, you have a race condition on your call to `OnProgressUpdateList`. If another thread unsubscribes after the `null` check but before the call you'll get an exception. You need to copy the event delegate to a local variable before invoking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an answer to myself as I couldn't get one here and I finally figured it out so for anyone looking for that in the future - here you go:

```
public partial class SomeClass {

public Subject<string> outputLogSubject = new Subject<string>();

public IObservable<string> OutputLog => outputLogSubject.AsObservable();

//Add string for collection updating UI
outputLogSubject.OnNext(string);


//After finishing the work you can call outputLogSubject.OnCompleted() to stop buffering
outputLogSubject.OnCompleted();

}
```

It needs to be added in the class that will be calling the executing the work.

Below needs to be added in the UI thread after initialization and BEFORE processing work :

```
var buffer = someClass.OutputLog.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), 6);
var chunked = buffer.ObserveOnDispatcher(DispatcherPriority.Background);
var update = chunked.Subscribe(name =>
{
foreach (var item in name)
  {
OutputLog.AppendText(item);
  }
OutputLog.ScrollToEnd();
});
```

This allowed me to keep the UI responsive to the point of seeing the output log is real time

Comment: Careful with this implementation. Calling `outputLogSubject.OnCompleted()` stops any new subscriptions from operating. You're better off either disposing of the subscription - which you should do - or implementing `IDisposable` on the `SomeClass` object and managing its lifetime that way.

Comment: Bottom-line, don't publicly expose your `Subject`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm aware of not exposing subject publicly - The code that I've seeen that has been implementing this was noting that, it's the whole reason why (in my code) IObservable<string> OutputLog exists in the first place. This code is just a first thing that has worked for me and I'm going to tune that later down the line as there are more things that I can optimize here.

As for the first comment, I'm also aware of that, in my code it's being called when all of the processing is being done hence subscription is no longer needed. I've checked in source that it calls Dispose() method.